# Awk compare current with next

Tags: text-processing, awk

My input file is:

```
     puloto_cluster_b_02_sys
puloto_cluster_b_02_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
        puloto_cluster_b_02_temp
        puloto_cluster_b_04_sys
puloto_cluster_b_04_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
        puloto_cluster_b_04_temp
        puloto_cluster_b_06_sys
puloto_cluster_b_06_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
        puloto_cluster_b_08_sys
puloto_cluster_b_08_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
        puloto_cluster_b_10_sys
puloto_cluster_b_10_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
```

I want my out put like this:

```
puloto_cluster_b_02_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_02_temp
puloto_cluster_b_04_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_04_temp
puloto_cluster_b_06_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_08_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_10_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
```

That is compare current record ($1) with next record ($1) then print next record only. If don't match print current one.

Comment: Why shouldn't the second line of the input be printed twice? The line previous to it matches, and it does not match the one after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{
         items++;
         if ($1 == f1) { print; items = 0 }
         else if (items == 2) { sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "", prev); print prev; items-- }
     }
     { prev = $0; f1 = $1 }' file
```

The output:

```
puloto_cluster_b_02_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_02_temp
puloto_cluster_b_04_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_04_temp
puloto_cluster_b_06_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_08_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_10_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `GNU sed` tool:

```
sed -Ee '
   $!N
   /^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]{1,})([[:blank:]]|\n)(.*\n){0,1}\1([[:blank:]]|$)/D
   s/^[[:blank:]]*//;P;D
'  input_file
```

Explanation:

- `$!N` bring the next line into the pattern space so long as it's not the last.
- `/^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]{1,})([[:blank:]]|\n)(.*\n){0,1}\1([[:blank:]]|$)/D`

  - Current line's first field matches the next line's first field then chop away the first line from the pattern space and go back to the top of the sed script with the truncated pattern space.
  - OTW, we print the first line and then chop it and branch back to the top of the sed script and apply the sed commands on truncated pattern space.

Output:

```
puloto_cluster_b_02_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_02_temp
puloto_cluster_b_04_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_04_temp
puloto_cluster_b_06_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_08_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
puloto_cluster_b_10_sys puloto_cluster_b_generic_cg
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk '{
b=$1
sub("^[[:blank:]]*","")
a=$0
while(getline) {
    if($1!=b)
        print a
    sub("^[[:blank:]]*","")
    a=$0
    b=$1
    }
print a
}' infile
```